# Can't add constraint to method

Tags: swift, core-data, protocols, combine

I'm trying to create a publisher for CoreData changes.

I've implemented Publisher protocol and I was required to implement NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate in same type (not in extension).

Next, I need to implement different NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods for different Outputs.

But when I add constraint *where* to method, xcode tells that it is not protocol method but "nearly matches optional requirement" and this method not called.

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) 
    where Output == [T]
{

}

func controller(
    _ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>,
    didChangeContentWith snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference)
    where Output == PublishedSnapshot
{

}
```

[image]
[image]

I can't implement both methods without any conditions because ```controller(:didChangeContentWith) hides all other delegate methods.

What should I do to implement different methods depending on Output type?

Comment: Why do you need different delegate methods for different Output types?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, because "I can't implement both methods without any conditions because ```controller(:didChangeContentWith) hides all other delegate methods."